# Pictures are not getting updated in database even after submitting using DJANGO Model Forms

Tags: python, django, django-models

I intend to make a user profile model with profile picture in django.

Everything works fine but I can't update the profile picture of the user.

The form is being displayed on the website but on clicking submit, no changes are visible in the database and the image is also not getting uploaded.

Below is my code for the form in HTML.

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'profile' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                {{ form.as_p }}

                                  <br><br>
                                <div class="mb-3"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="_picture" type="submit">Change Photo</button></div>
                            </form>
```

Below is the code models.py, for creating user profile model.

```
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):

    # Create relationship (don't inherit from User!)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    isInstructor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.ManyToManyField(Role)

    profile_picture = models.FileField(upload_to='static/profile_pic/'+str(time.time()),default='d.jpeg')

    address = models.TextField(max_length=256)
    city = models.TextF
class UpdateProfilePic(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfileInfo
        fields = ['profile_picture']
```

Below is the code for views.py

```
    @login_required
   def profile(request):

    current_user_profile = UserProfileInfo.objects.get(user=request.user)
    current_user = request.user

    form = UpdateProfilePic(instance=current_user_profile)

    context = {'current_user':current_user,'current_user_profile':current_user_profile,'form':form}
    if request.method=='POST':

        if '_user' in request.POST:
            temp_user = request.user
            temp_user.username = request.POST.get('username')
            temp_user.email = request.POST.get('email')
            temp_user.first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
            temp_user.last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
            temp_user.save()
            context = {'current_user':current_user,'current_user_profile':current_user_profile,'form':form}
            return render(request,'instructor_app/profile.html',context)

        if '_profile' in request.POST:
            temp_user_profile = UserProfileInfo.objects.get(user=request.user)
            temp_user_profile.address = request.POST.get('address')
            temp_user_profile.city = request.POST.get('city')
            temp_user_profile.pincode = request.POST.get('pincode')
            temp_user_profile.save()
            context = {'current_user':current_user,'current_user_profile':current_user_profile,'form':form}
            return render(request,'instructor_app/profile.html',context)

        if '_picture' in request.POST:
            print("in picture")
            form = UpdateProfilePic(request.POST, instance=UserProfileInfo.objects.get(user=request.user))
            form.save()
            context = {'current_user':current_user,'current_user_profile':current_user_profile,'form':form}
            return render(request,'instructor_app/profile.html',context)
    else:
        return render(request,'instructor_app/profile.html',context)
```

Help me with the code, please!

Comment: I think your views.py is incomplete. Can you please update your code with full views.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit your model by creating a model form or a simple Django form as shown below and by using the action attribute of form for passing the files.

You can try this:

form.py

```
from django import forms


class UpdateProfilePic(forms.Form):
    image = forms.ImageField()
```

In your views.py

```
if '_picture' in request.POST:
            form = UpdateProfilePic(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                m = UserProfileInfo.objects.get(user=request.user)
                m.profile_picture = form.cleaned_data['image']
                m.save()
                return redirect('/profile')
```

And your HTML file

```
<form action="{% url 'profile' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="custom-file">
                                          <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile04" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon04" name="image">
                                          <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile04">Choose file</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="input-group-append">
                                          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="_picture" id="inputGroupFileAddon04">Upload</button>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>

                                </form>
```